# Open a new Chrome window for another User using Launchy

Tags: google-chrome

Ive been trying to create a Launchy shortcut which will use the run command to open a new google chrome window for any of the four accounts I might access.

I know I can click on the top left corner and choose a profile, but I want to be able to do this regardless of whether chrome is running, and without picking up the mouse.

I know chrome can create shortcuts to the profiles on the desktop, which works, but pointing to these shortcuts in Launchy does not work.

I also know that the Windows Run command
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"
works very well to open my second profile, but pasting this command in Launchy does not work.
Any ideas/tips?
Tx
Fred

Comment: How about creating a shortcut / link / batch script (.bat file) for that chrome command (that you have there) and then add launchy to run those shortcut/batch file?